# Соответствие типов int и bool

Tags: c++

Как будет вести себя код

```
if (0) foo();
if (1) foo();
if (-1) foo();
```

То есть какие числа принимаются за истину, а какие за ложь?

Comment: true это любое ненулевое значение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все целые не равные нулю преобразуются к true, равные нулю к false. В вашем примере произойдет вызов во второй и третьей строчках. Правда я не понял, почему нельзя было это самому проверить.

Comment: Спасибо. Потому что с++ нету. На java в основном пишу. Порвал гугл, но не понял как правильно составить запрос для такой информации. А информация понадобилась для решения одной задачи на braingames. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Java не знаю, но думаю, что там такое-же поведение. По-другому я видел только в sh, bash и т.д. - там код возврата 0 - это true, а не 0 - false.

Comment: @dzhioev 
if (1) 
cannot convert int to boolean
if ((boolean) 1)
cannot cast int to boolean
В java придется делать так, чтобы стало как в си:
if ((n==0)?false:true)

Comment: Как в си? В си нет bool. Логические операции имеют значение 1 -- истина, 0 -- ложь. А вот операнды 0 -- ложь, не 0 -- истина.

Comment: @alexlz я имел ввиду, что if ((n==0)?false:true)  в ява аналогична if (n) в си

Comment: А зачем такие кучерявости. Чем не нравится `if (n!=0)`? Хотя можно и кучерявей расписать, только зачем?

Comment: @alexlz, верно. Видимо пора спать уже) Аж самому смешно стало)

Comment: @alexlz, в Си99 есть тип bool. Это, кажись, переопределенный char.

Comment: Си99? Заинтриговали...


         #define bool _Bool